# javascript send form to spring security validation

Tags: javascript, html, spring, xhtml, spring-security

I am need to submit an form through an link tag to spring security validation, but that is not working. Code is below:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="login" method="post" action="/j_spring_security_check">
        <fieldset>
            <input id="username" name="j_username" type="text"/>
            <input id="password" name="j_password" type="password"/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            <a href="" onclick="postForm();">Demo</a>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postForm()
    {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML="demo";
        document.getElementById("password").innerHTML="demo";
        document.getElementById("login").submit();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here when user click Demo link it should authorise and divert to demo page, but its not posting to spring security, while I submit through button is working. How can I authorize through an HTML link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of the `anchor` element

```
<a href="#" onclick="return postForm();">Demo</a>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postForm()
    {
        document.getElementById("username").value="demo";
        document.getElementById("password").value="demo";
        document.getElementById("login").submit();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K6CUn2XvSwl8DeqDW7ho?p=preview)

Comment: yeah, it was my mistake while writing on stackoverflow, on my code it has already closing curly brackets, but still not working...

Comment: @Olzhas also `.innerHTML` is wrong, you need to use `.value="demo"`

Comment: Nope, console doesnot show any errors, i have changed to '.value="demo"', still no success, but function gets called, as i check function with 'alert("function is called")' ,perhaps it is not submitting form in proper, no idea...

Comment: now code is getting better, its fills up the form, but perhaps .submit() is not working or its not accepted by spring security? i have no idea

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31932/discussion-between-olzhas-and-arun-p-johny)